Processing throughput ReactiveMessageConsumer is too low when using Reactive Pulsar Client
I essentially consume a flux of messages (consumeMany(..)) from topic A, transform them, and immediately send/pipe the result to reactive sender (using sendMany(..)) on topic B. I also register the time that a message has been waiting on topic A, before being processed. The problem is that this 'waiting time' initially fluctuates around 4 secs and even rises till 25 secs as I raise the frequency of messages produced on topic A; in any case, messages on topic A are sent at quite a low frequency (only a few every 10 secs, max 7-8 per 10 seconds).
To give you an idea, this is the rate at which messages are sent on topic A:

And this is the rate at which messages are taken from topic A and processed:

And this is the problem: the time a message has been waiting on topic A before being processed:

This is the relevant code: first, the reactive message consumer and sender:
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class PulsarReactiveConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ReactivePulsarClient reactivePulsarClient(@Value("${pulsar.broker.url}") String pulsarBrokerUrl) throws Exception {
        PulsarClient pulsarClient =
                PulsarClient.builder().serviceUrl(pulsarBrokerUrl)
                        //.loadConf(Map.of("autoConnectTopics", true))
                        .build();
        return AdaptedReactivePulsarClientFactory.create(pulsarClient);
    }

    @Bean(name = "consumer")
    ReactiveMessageConsumer<String> adjustmentBookedIntegrationEventConsumer(
            ReactivePulsarClient reactivePulsarClient,
            @Value("${pulsar.consumers.topicName}") String topic,
            @Value("${pulsar.defaults.consumer.tenant}") String tenant,
            @Value("${pulsar.defaults.consumer.namespace}") String namespace,
            @Value("${pulsar.consumers.subscriptionName}") String subscriptionName) {
        return reactivePulsarClient.messageConsumer(Schema.STRING)
                .topic("persistent://" + tenant + "/" + namespace + "/" + topic)
                .subscriptionInitialPosition(SubscriptionInitialPosition.Earliest)
                .subscriptionType(SubscriptionType.Key_Shared)
                .subscriptionName(subscriptionName)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sender")
    ReactiveMessageSender<String> worktimePrioritizationCalculatedIntegrationEventSender(
            ReactivePulsarClient reactivePulsarClient,
            @Value("${pulsar.producers.topicName}") String topic,
            @Value("${pulsar.defaults.producer.tenant}") String tenant,
            @Value("${pulsar.defaults.producer.namespace}") String namespace,
            @Value("${pulsar.producers.producerName}") String producerName) {
        return reactivePulsarClient.messageSender(Schema.STRING)
                .topic("persistent://" + tenant + "/" + namespace + "/" + topic)
                .accessMode(ProducerAccessMode.Shared)
                .producerName(producerName)
                .build();
    }

}

And this is the code that transforms the incoming Flux into an outgoing Flux:
   @PostConstruct
    void start() {
        Flux<MessageSpec<String>> outFlux = consumer.consumeMany(
                        influx -> influx.map(message -> MessageResult.acknowledge(message.getMessageId(), new InboundMessageAndMetadata(deserializeAdjustmentBookedIntegrationEvent(message), new PulsarMetaData(message))))
                )
                // register the latency due to waiting in Pulsar, in Prometheus
                .map(mnm -> registerWaitingInTopicLatency(mnm.message(), mnm.metaData()))
                .map(mnm -> {
                    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>(mnm.metaData().getProperties());
                    properties.put("publishedBy", "ce-fake-everesst");
                    return MessageSpec.builder(serializeWorktimePrioritizationCalculatedIntegrationEvent(transformationService.transformMessage(mnm.message())))
                            .properties(properties)
                            .key(mnm.message.agreementNumber())
                            .build();
                }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());

// send, after having generated some additional latency of 0 - 2 secs 
       sender.sendMany(outFlux.delayElements(generateLatency())).subscribe(m -> 
// register nb of processed messages as a Counter in Prometheus
this.nbMessagesProcessed.increment());
    }

Is using consumeMany() a good idea here? Would consumeOne() be more performing? If not so, how can I increase the processing speed/throughput?
